# Combing OverlayFS with A/B partition scheme

Tags: partition, grub2, fstab, overlayfs

I'm wondering if it's possible to combine OverlayFS with A/B upgrade scheme and do so in a completely RO only way. This combines a few pieces of technology, so I'm not sure if its possible or the correct place to look at

By A/B partitioning scheme I mean where I have two bootable partitions, then an upgrade consists of upgrading the inactive partition then switching over. This currently works for me today, with the caveat that I have to modify the inactive partitions /etc/fstab. I do that so I can modify the label of root.

In other words If my current active device is "SystemA", then once I have written the new image to the inactive partition. I mount the inactive partition and modify the inactive paritions `/etc/fstab` to something like

```
LABEL=SystemB / ext4 defaults 0 0
```

My devices and partitions will look like

```
NAME   MOUNTPOINT     LABEL       SIZE 
sda                             223.6G 
├─sda1 /boot_infra    boot          2G 
├─sda2                systema     20G 
├─sda3 /media/root-ro systemb     20G 
└─sda4 /media/root-rw overlayfs
```

We then have custom grub tooling that determines what partition to use. We modify this on our boot_partition using `grub-editenv`

Then when I boot OverlayFS takes over and sets everything up correctly.

However for various reasons (corporate/customer security type things), I need to eliminate the modifying fstab step.  I need the inactive partition to be completely RO, with no modifications to the image.

I **think** what I'm trying to do is have FSTAB dynamically resolve what label to use without hardcoding this into the FSTAB like I am currently